# How to use popBackStackImmediate by allowing state loss commit

Tags: android, fragment, fragment-transitions

I have a call of popBackStackImmediate in my Activity. I want to make a call to this method, but allowing stateloss commit as it is doing this method: `commitAllowingStateLoss`.
Is there a way for this?